# Not able to access the tables from H2 database using Java

Tags: h2, database-testing

I created a script for Database Testing using H2 database. I am facing issue, not able to read the tables in database. It throwing the message "Table not Found" and below code. But it is able to connect the database.

Configuration : h2-3.3.jar and h2.jar for Database Engine

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver"); 
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:C:\\keymanager\\etc\\H2/kms;CIPHER=AES","km_user","87654321 12345678");
System.out.println(con.getCatalog());
Statement statement = con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet resultSet1 = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM KM_AUDITLOGS");
while(resultSet1.next()){
  System.out.println("CREATEDATE:" +resultSet1.getString("USERIP"));
}
```

After executing the Script error message has been displayed

> "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table KM_AUDITLOGS not found; SQL statement:
>   SELECT * FROM KM_AUDITLOGS [42102-73]"

Any one can help me?

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table in question.

Comment: You are using a very old version of H2, version 1.0.73 from 2008. I suggest to upgrade to a more recent version (the build number is included in the error code).

Comment: Connecting to the database will always work: if the database doesn't exist yet, a new, empty database is created. This is probably what happened. To _not_ automatically create a new database, append `;ifexists=true` to the database URL.

Comment: Above installed h2-3.3.jar files is latest one

Comment: I don't know where you have a file named `h2-3.3.jar`, but it is definitely not from the H2 web site. Also, the error code [42102-73] clearly means you are using version 1.0.73 from 2008.

Comment: Thanks if replaced with latest version of H2, it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

When using the latest version of H2, it is working (according to the last comment).